# MYSQL COMPARE+DATETIME WITH SUBSTR?

Tags: mysql, datetime, compare, substr

If someone could tell me if that method is good enough and works please :

```
SELECT 
            idusers, 
            nom, 
            prenom, 
            email, 
            SUBSTR( lastlogin, 1, 10), 
            genre 
        FROM 
            users 
                WHERE 
                    active = 1 
                        AND 
                    is_banned != 1
                        AND 
                    SUBSTR( lastlogin, 1, 10) < '2013-10-14'
                        OR 
                    active = 1 
                        AND 
                    is_banned != 1
                        AND 
                    lastlogin IS NULL
```

According to the "SUBSTR( lastlogin, 1, 10) < '2013-10-14'" that apparently works but i am not sure if this is the best way to find people that has not logged in since 2 weeks.

Cheers !

Comment: Evidently DATETIME Format is "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:000" OR Null

Answer (score 0):

you should not be relying on the default string format of a `DATE` column. Instead, mysql has a bunch of date manipulation functions you could use:

```
SELECT idusers, 
       nom, 
       prenom, 
       email, 
       DATE_FORMAT (last_login, ;%y-%m-%d)
       genre 
FROM   users
WHERE  active =1
       AND
       is_banned != 1
       AND 
       (DATE_DIFF(CURDATE(), last_login) >= 14 OR lst_login IS NULL)
```